# Laravel sending data by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I am trying to send data from my form to back-end by ajax but it doesn't send all my data.

## preview of sent data

```
array:6 [
  "title" => "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  "slug" => "xxxxxx"
  "description" => """xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"""
  "publish" => "1"
  "user_id" => "1"
  "thumbnail" => null
]
```

### Issues

1. my `description` is in triple double qoute `""" xxxx """` (not sure if it's ok)
2. Image (thumbnail) didn't send
3. Categories didn't send

## code

`form`

```
{{ Form::model($post, array('route' => array('quickedit', $post->id), 'method' => 'POST', 'files' => true)) }}
<div class="modal-body text-left">
    {{-- show success message --}}
    <div class="msg"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
            {{ Form::label('title', 'Title') }}
            {{ Form::text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
            {{ Form::label('slug', 'Slug') }}
            {{ Form::text('slug', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
            {{ Form::label('description', 'Description') }}
            {{ Form::textarea('description', null, array('class' => 'form-control editor')) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
            <div class="row">
                @if(!empty($post->thumbnail))
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{url('/images')}}/{{$post->thumbnail}}" alt="{{$post->title}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        {{ Form::label('thumbnail', 'Thumbnail') }}
                        {{ Form::file('thumbnail', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                    </div>
                @else
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        {{ Form::label('thumbnail', 'Thumbnail') }}
                        {{ Form::file('thumbnail', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                    </div>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
            {{ Form::label('publish', 'Publish') }}
            <select name="publish" id="publish" class="custom-select">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="1" {{ $post->publish == '1' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Publish</option>
                <option value="0" {{ $post->publish == '0' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Draft</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
            {{ Form::label('categories', 'Categories') }}
            <select name="categories[]" id="categories" class="custom-select selectbox" multiple>
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->title}}</option>
                    @if(count($category->children) > 0)
                        @foreach($category->children as $children)
                            <option class="pl-2" value="{{$children->id}}">{{$children->title}}</option>

                            @if(count($children->children) > 0)
                                @foreach($children->children as $child)
                                    <option class="pl-4" value="{{$child->id}}">{{$child->title}}</option>

                                    @if(count($child->children) > 0)
                                        @foreach($child->children as $childf)
                                            <option class="pl-5" value="{{$childf->id}}">{{$childf->title}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="msg"></div>
</div>
{{Form::close()}}

<button class="btn btn-primary updatepost" data-id="{{$post->id}}" type="submit">Update</button>
```

`JavaScript`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.updatepost').click(function (event) {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
    });

    event.preventDefault();

    var title = $('input[name="title"]').val();
    var slug = $('input[name="slug"]').val();
    var description = $('.editor').val();
    var publish = $('#publish option:selected').val();
    var user_id = $('input[name="user_id"]').val();
    var thumbnail = $('input[name="thumbnail"]').val();
    var categories= $('#categories option:selected').val();

    // $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");

    var prdfoId = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{url("/admin/quickedit")}}/'+encodeURI(prdfoId),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json", 
            data: {
                title: title,
                slug:slug,
                description: description,
                publish: publish,
                user_id: user_id,
                thumbnail: thumbnail,
                categories: categories
            },
            success:function(data) {
                $('.msg').empty().append("Updated Successfully"); 
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

`route`

```
Route::post('quickedit/{id}','BlogController@quickedit')->name('quickedit');
```

`controller`

```
public function quickedit(Request $request, $id)
    {
        dd($request->all());
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'title' => 'required',
            'slug' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'user_id' => 'required|numeric',
            'thumbnail' => 'nullable|image',
            'publish' => 'required|numeric',
        ));

        $post = Post::find($id);
        $post = Post::where('id',$id)->first();

        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->slug = $request->input('slug');
        $post->description = $request->input('description');
        $post->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
        $post->publish = $request->input('publish');

        if ($request->hasFile('thumbnail')) {
            $thumbnail = $request->file('thumbnail');
            $filename = 'Post' . '-' . time() . '.' . $thumbnail->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = public_path('images/' . $filename);
            Image::make($thumbnail)->resize(850, 565)->save($location);
            $post->thumbnail = $filename;

            $oldFilename = $post->thumbnail;
            $post->thumbnail = $filename;
            Storage::delete($oldFilename);
        }

        $post->save();
        $post->tags()->sync($request->tags);
        $post->categories()->sync($request->categories);
    }
```

Any idea?

## Update

Based on answer and comments the last code I ended up is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.updatepost').click(function (event) {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
    });

    event.preventDefault();

    var title = $('input[name="title"]').val();
    var slug = $('input[name="slug"]').val();
    var description = $('.editor').val();
    var publish = $('#publish option:selected').val();
    var user_id = $('input[name="user_id"]').val();

    var thumbnail = $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0];

    var categories= [];
    $("#categories option:selected").each(function(){
        categories.push($(this).val());
    });
    categories = JSON.stringify(categories);

    //new
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('thumbnail', thumbnail);
    formData.append('title', title);
    formData.append('slug', slug);
    formData.append('description', description);
    formData.append('publish', publish);
    formData.append('user_id', user_id);
    formData.append('categories', categories);
    //new


    var prdfoId = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{url("/admin/quickedit")}}/'+encodeURI(prdfoId),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json", 
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(data) {
                $('.msg').empty().append("Updated Successfully"); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The result of this code is:

```
array:7 [
  "thumbnail" => "undefined"
  "title" => "xxxxxxx"
  "slug" => "xxxxxxxxx"
  "description" => """
    xxxxx
   """
  "publish" => "1"
  "user_id" => "1"
  "categories" => "[]"
]
```

### issues

1. image is undefined
2. categories are not passed
3. description is in triple double qoutes `""" xxxxx """`

any idea?

Comment: I think you have to send `id` as well through AJAX

Comment: @Vpa i am  sending id as well `+encodeURI(prdfoId)`

Comment: ok, got it, if you use `name="categories[]"` means category name as array, shouldn't you have to handle the array?

Comment: @Vpa I'm aware of that, i have no idea how? :)

Comment: @Vpa that's one of the issues.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel-form, what will be happen if you call description by name, not by class. will it remove `"""` triple quote

Comment: i try..........

Comment: i get undefined.

Comment: did you do like `$('input[name="description"]').val();`

Comment: yes............

Comment: for categories array you can use  javascript `length` property.. but not sure

Comment: any sample?.....

Comment: @Vpa updated........

Answer (score 0):

Your `quickedit` method calling `dd()`, what dump data, then just die. Also, `quickedit` returns void. In must to be an object or array if you going to use AJAX+JSON.

Comment: I'm using dd in order to see what data are passing and what doesn't which is helped me to make this question `dd` is not my issue, my issue is all my data are not passing, just some.

Answer (score 0):

If you send image file you need has to base64 if you need handle in json, Or need use FormData like this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]); 

$.ajax({
    url: 'Your url here',
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS (requires jQuery 1.6+)
    processData: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS
    // ... Other options like success and etc
});
```

I think, a has a simplest way make two call firs send just json data, and then secound call is send the image.

```
 var title = $('input[name="title"]').val();
      var slug = $('input[name="slug"]').val();
      var description = $('.editor').val();
      var publish = $('#publish option:selected').val();
      var user_id = $('input[name="user_id"]').val();
      var thumbnail = $('input[name="thumbnail"]').prop('files');

      var categories= $('#categories option:selected').val();
      var formData = new FormData();
      //Add a the file to fomr data
      formData.append('image', thumbnail[0]); 
      //And need add data like this
      formdData.append('title',title );
```

Comment: so this passes my thumbnail field how i get rest of my fields in `formData` ? wouldyou please complete your answer?

Comment: The json fomrat is required for you? If not can you use append('key','value') any other data.

Comment: no, as long as i can send data no matter what format they are.

Comment: yes i read that but didn't get it, it uses static sample and not say how to get value from form (input field) :\

Comment: I add an example for the answer check it please

Comment: i'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined`

Comment: I modify the to: .prop('files') check this out

Comment: Try solve this proble, for get a file if this not work, try get element By id.